# PHPMyAdmin on Ubuntu: Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: ubuntu

As subject, my phpmyadmin installation on ubuntu have that error, did you know what it means and how to solve it?

Comment: Silly question, I should have searched it before asking:D
Found the answer here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7362860&postcount=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `config.inc.php` file on phpMyAdmin folder.

Find this line:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

Go to phpMyAdmin user privileges.
Then change the "pma" password.

Refresh your phpMyAdmin.

Comment: i didn't find where the config.inc.php file located?

Comment: It depends. If you install manually by download phpmyadmin from their website, you can find `config.inc.php` in root directory of phpmyadmin. But, if you install from package manager, let's say Ubuntu, you can find at `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.